# Does "with your pay" exist?

Tags: word-choice

I like the coat very much. —But can you afford such an expensive coat ____(on/ with) your pay? 
which option is right?

Comment: Either one works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I like the coat very much. —But can you afford such an expensive coat ____(on/ with) your pay? which option is right?

✤-----✤-----✤

It's certainly **'on'**.

-*But can you afford such an expensive coat **on** your pay/ salary?.*

-*I don't know how he can afford a new car **on** his salary.* - [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/afford)

*[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=afford%20it%20on%20my%20salary%2Cafford%20it%20with%20my%20salary&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cafford%20it%20on%20my%20salary%3B%2Cc0)* shows **'afford on'** but doesn't show **'afford with'**.

Comment: If one was emphasising the largeness of the pay I think "with" would work. e.g. *With his pay/income one might have expected him to buy a bigger house*. "With" is perhaps more idiomatic in Britain. Prepositions change, more than anything else, as one crosses the pond.

Comment: many thanks, they are very helpful.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Your evidence? "On" is not something I would use here.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul  I certainly don't rely on Google as a guide to the English language.

Answer (score 2):

## Both are correct.

Speaking as an Australian, I can say that both of those sound correct to me; if there’s a regional difference between British and American English, we’ve evidently gotten the best of both worlds here.

I think there might be a small difference in meaning, though; “on your pay” is a bit more referring to your ranking on a formal pay scale -e.g. “on apprentice wages”, whereas “with your pay” might be referring to your physical payments “going to the bank with my pay in my pocket”.